# Cannot use exec command at all, for any command, on PHP 8

Tags: php, exec, iis-10

When trying to run `http://example.com/exec.php` from a web browser, `exec` refuses to produce any useful result. What permissions do I need to change in order to be successful here?

---

Here is my code:

```
<?php
set_error_handler(function(int $errno, string $errstr, ?string $errfile = null, ?int $errline = null, ?array $errcontext = null) {
    throw new \ErrorException($errstr, $errno, E_ERROR, $errfile, $errline);
}, E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$command = 'echo "Hello"';
$command = 'dir';
$command = '"C:\\path\\to\\specific.exe"';
$command = 'whoami';

$result = exec($command . ' 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
var_dump($command);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($return_var);
var_dump($result);
```

For any and every single command I have tried, I get this result:

```
string(6) "whoami"
array(0) {
}
int(1)
string(0) ""
```

I can run `whoami` in the Administrator Command Prompt, and I get "pcname\adminstrator", so I know that, at the very least, "whoami" is a valid command to be run.

`disabled_functions` in php.ini is empty.

`open_basedir` is disabled.

`get_current_user` returns `IUSR`. I have given Read & Execute permissions to "specific.exe" to 'IUSR' and even 'IIS_IUSRS'.

---

I have no issues using `"C:\Program Files\PHP\php-8.1.5\php.exe" -f C:\inetpub\exec.php 2>&1` in the command line and getting the expected result:

```
string(6) "whoami"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(20) "pcname\administrator"
}
int(0)
string(20) "pcname\administrator"
```

Comment: I should note: It's not just limited to exec. shell_exec, popen, system, etc., all have the same issue.

Comment: I feel like I should also note: php versions 5.6.31 (x86) and 7.1.29 (x86) both produce the expected result. versions 7.4.20 (x64), 8.1.5 (x64), and 8.2.4 (x64) all have the same issue. Could this possibly be an issue with PHP 7.2+ or a 64-bit issue?

Comment: Since not only exec is limited, and it can work in php x86 version. The problem should be IIS configuration issue. You have checked the permissions, what error message do you get when you access the site in IIS? You need to generate logs with FRT to understand what's going on.

Comment: The _request_ isn't failing, the exec command is. Failed Request Tracing isn't going to help. What do you mean "access the site in IIS?"

Comment: It's a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue. I installed the 32-bit version, copied the ini file from the 64-bit version without any changes, and I'm getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using ProcessMonitor from Microsoft SysInternals, I discovered PHP checks a number of locations for `cmd.exe`. It first checks PHP's install directory, then a few other locations, and finally the system folders. 32-bit PHP was using `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`, and 64-bit PHP was using `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` (as they rightfully should be).

I fixed the issue for 64-bit PHP by creating a symbolic link to the 32-bit `cmd.exe` in the 64-bit PHP installation folder: `C:\Program Files\PHP\php-8.2.4>mklink cmd.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`